# Using UIPickerView to trigger population of a table from an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, uipickerview

Firstly I apologise if my thought process is completely wrong. I am pretty new to all this, (Less than two weeks from writing my first line of code to be honest!) but I think the functionality I am in need of should be possible

I am attempting to use a UIPickerView to select one of 40 options - the selected value is then intended to trigger the population of a small table with values from a second array.

I have so far managed to add and correctly configure the UIPickerView to read the first array, and to automatically return the value of the selected item in the picker to a UILabel (just to prove that I am getting the correct output from the Picker)

I am quite pleased with myself bearing in mind my amateur nature.

Essentially this initial array contains details of 40 organisations and the table I hope to display when one is selected will contain 6 to eight rows in two columns. The first column will be a heading (Address, Phone etc) and the second column will be a value specific to that organisation. 
The columns will be consistent across all the entries returning the same info for each organisation. In that respect I hope this question will be simpler for you experts than it could have been.

My code so far...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource  {

@IBOutlet weak var orgSelectedFromPicker: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var orgPicker: UIPickerView!

//function for the number of columns in the picker
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

//function counting the array to give the number of rows in the picker
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return orgPickerData.count
}

//function displaying the array rows in the picker as a string
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return orgPickerData[row]
}

//function allowing the font and colour of the picker to be changed
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {
    let titleData = orgPickerData[row]
    let myTitle = NSAttributedString(string: titleData, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Verdana", size: 15.0)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()])
    return myTitle
}

//function returning the selected row from the picker
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    self.orgSelectedFromPicker.text = orgPickerData[row]
}



//Array containing the list for UIPickerView
    var orgPickerData = [...........] //I've taken the values out of here for privacy purposes..........]
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.orgPicker.dataSource=self
    self.orgPicker.delegate=self

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

`

So - any ideas?